# How to list directories within the current directory in stata?

Tags: stata

I would like to print all the directories (and only directories) in my current directory using Stata. In Linux, I use:

```
ls -d */
```

This doesn't work in Stata. It looks like Stata don't recognize the wildcard character (`invalid '*'`). I also tried:

```
local subdirs : dir "." dirs "*"
```

which prints nothing.

I tried variations of the both commands but cannot print the directories names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `help` for `shell` or with your local macro approach

```
 di "`subdirs'"
```

to see the macro contents.

Comment: `shell` command works for me. Thanks! `di "subdirs'" ` returns a error related to my openssl, though. I will tried to fix it.

Comment: You need matching single quotes, as in my answer; you may have tried that, but as you've found it's the devil of a job to get Stata's single quotes shown properly here in comments, although not impossible.